# Google script cell validation on edit

Tags: javascript, validation, scripting, cell, startswith

The plan is to on edit a function to check cell contents because cell contents are being scanned in via barcode scanner. Sometimes the computer is a little slow and it doesn't register the first value, therefore since the first value is always going to be "B" we sometimes result with N-xxxxxxx instead of BN-xxxxxxx,

Here is what i have so far

```
var value = "n-1001234";
function validateBin(value)
{ var bin = this.value.toUpperCase();
  var n = bin.startsWith("BN-");
  if(n)
  {   }
  else
  {
  var newbin = bin.split("-");
  newbin[0] = "BN-";
  newbin.join();
  newbin;
  }

}
```

The error I keep encountering is the bin.startsWith() it keeps saying "TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith in object N-1001234. (line 1023, file "Utilities")" when debugging this in google scripts.

It passes through the value, makes it uppercase but I cannot get a value for N since it fails on that line

Answer (score 0):

use value.substring(0,1) to get the cell's first char.. if it is N, append B to value and replace cell's current value with new correct value... enhance example to suit your needs...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
//var value = "n-1001234";
function validateBin(value)
{ var bin = value.toUpperCase();
  var n = bin.substring(0,1);
  if(n=='N')
  {
  var newValue = 'B'+bin;
  alert(newValue);
  }
  else
  {

  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' onclick='validateBin("n-1001234")' value='test validate'/>
</body>
</html>
```